# How to jump more or less depending how much time you press the screen in Android (c#)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, time, screen

I'm doing a game to android with Unity and I don't know how to do to jump more or less depending how much time you press the screen, I tried it but I don't know how to do it, I used deltatime but it doesn't work, at least no at least not in the way I did it, so I would like to know how to do that. The character jumps but just a little bit, it doesn't matter how much time I press the screen, it jumps so low.

This is how I've tried to accomplish that:

```
void Update () {    
        movimiento ();

        if (transform.position.x <= 4.65f) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene ("Game Over");   
        }
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("Andar 2");
            print (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaTime);
            if (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaTime >= 2) {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 20000);
                GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("Andar 2");
            } else if (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaTime >= 1) {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 2000);
            } else if (Input.GetTouch (0).deltaTime < 1) {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * 200);    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to work with velocities directly when doing jumps as i feel like i can be more precise with it, But regardless, here is my solution for variable height jumps.

```
void Update ()
{
    // set jump controls
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        jump = true;

    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended && !grounded)
        jumpCancel = true;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // if player presses jump
    if (jump)
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, jumpVelocity, rigidbody.velocity.z);
        jump = false;
    }

    // if player performes a jump cancel
    if (jumpCancel)
    {
        if (rigidbody.velocity.y > shortJumpVelocity)
            rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, shortJumpVelocity, rigidbody.velocity.z);
        controller.jumpCancel = false;
    }
}
```

This works by altering the player's velocity if the finger is lifted before the shortJumpVelocity is reached. As you can see you will have to have a grounded state of some kind for this to work properly.

I love this method as it avoids timers and gives the player a lot of control.